# How can I run react-scripts in a react app created with vite

Tags: reactjs, vite, react-scripts

I have created a react app using vite. Vite doesn't refresh after every change i make in my code.
So, I want to run the app via react-scripts instead of vite.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: i think theres something wrong with your installation because vite offers fast refresh, make sure you have all the dependencies installed.